# GoogleTest tests don't start

Tags: c++, linux, googletest

It's my test fixture: https://github.com/patrykbajos/ZinotEngine/blob/master/src/tests/core/MapResMgrTest.cpp. 
My CMake file for this executable: https://github.com/patrykbajos/ZinotEngine/blob/master/ZinotEngine.cmake and CMakeLists for all executables https://github.com/patrykbajos/ZinotEngine/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt. I've compiled gtest from sources in apt-get package libgtest-dev on Ubuntu. Next I copied *.so files to /usr/lib and installed libgtest-dev packege because include files. I think that my test fixture is right. There are no compilation errors. My exec runs an usually and displays:

```
/home/patryk/ClionProjects/BennuEngine/bin/Debug/ZinotEngine
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
Hello world!!!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've added some lines to CMake file but I think that it doesn't add *.cpp files containing tests to build executable. Here's these lines:

```
# Sources
file(GLOB_RECURSE ZINOTENGINE_SRC "src/zinot/core/*.c" "src/zinot/core/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE ZINOTENGINETESTS_SRC "src/tests/*.cpp")

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL "Debug")
    message("Debug << dodawanie testów.")
    set(ZINOTENGINE_SRC "${ZINOTENGINE_SRC} ${ZINOTENGINETESTS_SRC}")
endif ()

# Binary
add_executable(ZinotEngine ${ZINOTENGINE_SRC})
```

It's my whole repository of code: https://github.com/patrykbajos/ZinotEngine.

PS. I'm compiling my project by CLion with `Configuration: Debug` on `Build All`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug. It was in:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL "Debug")
    message("Debug << dodawanie testów.")
    set(ZINOTENGINE_SRC "${ZINOTENGINE_SRC} ${ZINOTENGINETESTS_SRC}")
endif ()
```

It should be:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    #message("Debug << dodawanie testów.")
    set(ZINOTENGINE_SRC "${ZINOTENGINE_SRC};${ZINOTENGINETESTS_SRC}")
endif ()
```

I though that separator of source files is space but it's semicolon.